# How does one use XGBoost 0.90

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am having this error that when I am trying to add a version where the XGB version is `0.90`, I get that the only available corresponding ML version is `2.1` but the problem is when I click save, I get an error -in my console- that says

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Selected framework (XGBOOST) is not available for runtime version 2.1.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
```

If anyone has any idea on how to solve this I would be quite grateful

Comment: Can yo elaborate on what you were using please? Were you trying to create a model on Google Cloud Console?

Comment: @GuoqingXu Yes, that was exactly what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Runtime version 2.1 currently only supports TF 2.1. Support for XGB 0.90 in that runtime version is planned in the near future. You can check up-to-date status on what versions of frameworks are supported at the below link.

https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list